# Downloaded some repositories with gip (for windows 8.1), but they are not in my folder

Tags: windows, git

So, I downloaded git today to get some files, used standard installation options and then used windows' cmd and typed in:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

to select my folder and then

```
git clone git://github.com/FrictionalGames/HPL1Engine.git
```

and others, following the istrucions I have been given on a "how to do" forum.
Everything worked fine, I had confirm my repositories where saved, but when I checked that folder it was empty.

Not completly obviously, there are git, gitk and start-ssh-agent but not trace of what I needed.

If I try to search them from search they are not on my computer, if I trey to download them again it says: *fatal destination path 'HPL1Engine' already exists and is not an empty directory*

How can I solve it?

Comment: Then clearly the repository *was* downloaded and you are using the wrong tool to look for it, or looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Don't download repositories into a program files folder. Go to Documents or something else and try from there. Then try to specify destination folder if needed like `git clone git://github.com/FrictionalGames/HPL1Engine.git HPLP1Engine`

Comment: Jepessen, If I do that then windows' cmd does not recognize git as a command. I tried from Git Bash (I have not idea what it is) and download worked, but I don't know where repo is right know. Only hint is /usr, which I can't find

Comment: Adding the directory to your `PATH` should enable you to run Git from any directory.  You really should not litter the program directory with checkouts.

Comment: Can you make a example for me? Because I really think that's what I'm doing, but it doesn't work...